# INDEX MATCH function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a problem using the INDEX + MATCH function. In the attached file I have a table with 9 different index names [Columns K2:S2] which in turn are the same ones that appear in Column A, now I need to organize the information for each of them, that is to say that the data that is recorded in Column A [cells A2:A1964] is replicated and matched with the corresponding column names [K2:S2] for each respective index.

The operation I want to perform is if the value of cell K$2 matches the value of column $A$3:$A$1964 and the value of cell $I3 matches the value of column $C$3:$C$1946, bring me the corresponding value of column $E$3:$E$1964.

If the value of cell L$2 matches the value of column $A$3:$A$1964 and the value of cell $I3 matches the value of column $C$3:$C$1946, bring me the corresponding value of column $E$3:$E$1964.

If the value of cell S$2 matches the value of column $A$3:$A$1964 and the value of cell $I3 matches the value of column $C$3:$C$1946, bring me the corresponding value of column $E$3:$E$1964.

Edit: I have made some adjustments to find a solution to the case. The fact is that for column K I have introduced the formula `INDEX($E$3:$E$1964,MATCH($I3,$C$3:$C$1964,0))`.

While for the other columns ranging from L:S I have noted `INDEX($E3:$E$1964,MATCH(L$2,$A$3:$A$1964,0))......INDEX($E3:$E$1964,MATCH(S$2,$A$3:$A$1964,0))`.

I know that it is possible to write a uniform formula to apply in all cells of the table K2: S220, but I have not been able to find it yet.

[worksheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NN1TXcnXWRZMo7ed19jOBJdI9hznA3_B/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets, use this in `K3` and copy it to the whole area.

```
=index($E:$E,match(concatenate(K$2,$I3),$A:$A&$C:$C,0))
```

In Excel, you would have to use this **slow** version (array formula):

```
=INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(1,(K$2=$A:$A)*($I3=$C:$C),0))
```

or this **quicker** version (array formula):

```
=INDEX($E3:$E1964,MATCH(1,(K$2=$A3:$A1964)*($I3=$C3:$C1964),0))
```

Comment: Dear, thanks for your collaboration, unfortunately it is not the answer I am looking for, besides the solution you propose gives me an error "# N / A" as a result. What I am looking for is to organize the information that initially appears in rows [E3: E1964], so that they appear in columns [K3: K220] ... [S3: S220], taking into account that the data correspond to each index [ A3: A1964]

Comment: Do you know that **array formulas** are entered not using ENTER key, but instead, CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER ?

Comment: Yes, as you describe, first select the matrix where I want to replicate the formula, then type F2 and enter the expression (formula) and then press CTRL + SHIFT + ENT, and this time I get the same number (result) in all cells.

Comment: OK, I see the problem. You don't need to select the whole matrix at the beginning! Only select K3. Paste the formula and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Only THEN you can copy the formula.

Comment: Perfect, this time it worked following your indications, but it was necessary to copy the formula in the other cells so that I can effectively perform the calculation. Can you please tell me how the syntax of your formula works?, it is a little confusing for me to understand the first argument [1] in the MATCH function. Thanks for your valuable information!

Comment: Nice to hear, Camila. For explanation, I think these guys do it pretty well: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 0):

1. I have simplified the data given by you, in my form as per the Image Shown Below.
   Taking three columns: Series Code, Country Code, Values
2. Then by making a Table, Taking Series and Country on Either Side of the table, I have entered formulae.
3. In each Cell of the table, I have first entered the formula in first cell of the row.
4. Copy the formula, across the row. Formulae are self explanatory.
   Series Code Country Code    Value Y         Series >>>  A   B   C   D       Total
   Country X   15  15  20  25      75
   A   X   15          Y   30  10  20  30      90
   C   Y   20          Z   0   10  15  5       30
   B   Z   10          T   15  20  0   25      60
   D   T   5           P   35  20  30  10      95
   A   P   20
   C   P   15          Total   95  75  85  95      350
   B   X   10
   D   Y   5
   D   Z   0
   A   T   15
   C   P   5
   B   P   20      G3   =  SUMIFS($C$4:$C$29,$A$4:$A$29,G1,$B$4:$B$29,$F$3)        Copy Across the row
   D   X   25
   A   Y   30      G7  =   SUMIFS($C$4:$C$29,$A$4:$A$29,G1,$B$4:$B$29,$F$7)        Copy Across the row
   C   Z   15
   B   T   20
   D   P   10
   A   P   0
   C   X   20
   B   Y   10
   D   Z   5
   D   T   20
   A   P   15
   C   P   10
   B   X   5
   D   Y   25

   Total   350

Do it for all other rows.
The data and formula, you will find in the Iamage, attached herewith.
By the way, In any Cell, by pressing Edit Button, F2, you can visualise the connected cell. This help us in correcting the formula, when we go wrong.
I hope, I have solved, as per your requirement.
Thanks, for giving me the opportunity to serve.

P.S. I tried several times as I wanted to add Image of Worksheet, but I failed, I dont know how to do it. At last I copied everything in Word, and pasted here it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult for me to enter my explanation and then worksheet along with, because I dont know.
Then I got the Solution by pasting both in Word, which appeared perfect to me.

But when it is pasted here, It disorganize all columns and rows, and EDIT sheet down my answer becomes very clumsy, difficult to understand.

So now I narrate, in short what I did.

Entered title in A1, B1, C1 as : Series Code, Country Code, Values.
In A3:A28 Values of Series Code varying from A, B, C, D. ( Four Series )
In B3:B28 Values of Country Code varying from X, Y, Z, T, P. ( Five Countries )
In C3:C28 ; Corrosponding data values : 15,20,10,5,20,15, 10,5,0,15,5, 20,25,30,15,20,
10,0,20,10,5,20,15,10,5,25.
In all, 26 values, adding to  Total of 350.
THen based on this another table is prepared as explained; Column Headings Series, A, B, C, D. in G1, H1, I1,J1 And Row Headings Country ; X, Y, Z, T, P. in the cells F2,F3, F4, F5, F6.
The TABLE AREA is G2:J6.
Now I hope, it is clear.
Very sorry for wasting time of many.

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for your valuable collaboration, but the answer is a bit confusing as I can't replicate it in a spreadsheet; maybe I have formulated the question wrong so I will rephrase it, I have already found a possible solution but the truth seems to me a bit rudimentary, and it is possible that everything can be done with a single expression.

Comment: For Column K of the new table I have raised the expression `INDEX($E$3:$E$1964,MATCH($I3,$C$3:$C$1964,0))`, to obtain the values corresponding to the value of that column.

While for Columns L to S I have raised the expression `INDEX($E3:$E$1964,MATCH(L$2,$A$3:$A$1964,0)) ...... INDEX($E3:$E$1964,MATCH(S$2,$A$3:$A$1964,0))`